# Tela preta ao compilar apk Android para Delphi X5 para Asus Live

Tags: android, delphi-xe5

Eu estou simplesmente criando uma aplicação com um botão, mais nada, só para fazer rodar uma app no Asus Live, mas quando envio o app para o celular ele simplesmente fica com a tela toda preta e depois de um tempo fecha. O mesmo app no Zenfone 2 roda tranquilamente.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poder ser pela versão do Android, o seu Asus Live é superior a 5.0?... e o ZenFone 2 inferior a 5.0, você precisa baixar o HotFix que a embarcadero lançou , assim os aplicativos vão funcionar em Android's superiores a 5.0.

http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30110 entre com usuário e senha que foram usados para registrar a licença e baixe ele.